# Is FluentValidation middleware enough in .NETCore WebAPI or should I validate in Service layer again?

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

I have a very simple 3-tier layer `ASP.NET Core WebAPI` application:

1. **Domain** - with `Entities`, `Data interfaces`, `Services` and `DTO` objects (which are the only input and output objects). So *"the interface of the Domain"* are Services that accepts input DTOs and returns output DTOs.
2. **Infrastructure** - Implementation of the `Data interfaces` (Data repositories) and CodeFirst Migrations.
3. **WebAPI** - Standard ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API project.

The WebAPI project returns "Output" DTOs in Controllers. For endpoints that accepts payload, "Input" DTOs are used. Controllers are very much similar to the Services from the Domain. Controllers expose Domain Services to the world (obviously, the interface of the Domain).

But then comes the Validation... I'm familiar with FluentValidation and with the ASP.NET Core plumbing - it's an awesome middleware:

```
        services.AddControllers()
            .AddFluentValidation(opt =>
            {
                opt.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining(typeof(PersonInputValidator));
            });
```

I implement validation for each "Input" DTO and this works great, BUT... I'm not sure if this is enough. If you take any Service class, it's pretty much not validated. It's .NET Core middleware that technically validates the input to the Controller.

Should I "double-validate" within Services again?
If so, is there a smooth way to reuse Validators I already have?

Comment: If you think you will have other consuming layers, not just via WebAPI, say for example a XAML app, it would make sense to have the validation in the service layer. If you are certain WebAPI is your only consumer of the services, keep it simple as you've done.

Answer (score 6):

You should never have to run validations twice. The data from your web API should be validated. If you ever use your services with any other interface besides a web API, you could implement your fluent validations there too. 
Here is a good example for implementing fluent validations: https://github.com/jasontaylordev/NorthwindTraders

Answer (score 2):

With a service layer and presentation layer, I would normally do the FV implementation/dto validation at the service layer. That way the services can be reused and the validation goes with them.
It also allows you to keep your controllers lean.
In your controllers there may be scope to have presentation layer specific checks/validation eg the model binding failed. But that can just be a basic model state implementation, I wouldn't get FV onto this.

Comment: Can you give a brief example of using FV in service layer and how the validation is consumed by presentation layer, just to make this approach clear in your answer

Answer (score 2):

FluentValidations can be used in controllers while also keeping them lean. In the business layer, other validation rules can also be added but the model state is checked in the WebApi level which is the gateway to the system. FluentValidation uses middleware so the controller is not even hit if validation fails.
I also suggest implementing middleware which translates any exceptions thrown by the business layer into appropriate http status codes, which also leaves your controllers very clean.
In the business layer sometimes validation rules are also used, such as when you want to check that dependent data is present.